# How to retrieve forgotten Hotmail password

Tags: account-management, outlook.com, passwords

I have forgotten my Hotmail account password. What is the procedure to retrieve my password?

Note that I'm not asking where the link is. I want to learn about the procedure (i.e. if they ask me about my birthday, the secret question which I defined years ago, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reset your Hotmail password in two ways:

- By requesting a password reset e-mail, if you entered an alternative e-mail address for your Windows Live ID.
- By providing location information and the secret answer for the question you selected.

After clicking Hotmail's [Reset Password](https://account.live.com/ResetPassword.aspx) link, Hotmail takes you to Reset Password page along with a Captcha, offering you to choose one of these options:

- **Use my location information and secret answer to verify my identity:** If you select this, Hotmail wants answers to these questions: Country/region; Postal Code; Province; Secret answer to your secret question. If you give the correct answers, you are allowed to reset the password of your account.
- **Send password reset instructions to me in e-mail:** Password reset instructions are sent to your alternate e-mail address.